# Error: org.json.JSONException: An active access token must be used to query information

Tags: android

I am trying to extract json content from http://api.deezer.com/2.0/playlist/4341978 but my log print the error message below:

Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user","type":"OAuthException","code":200}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Json

```
{
"id": 4341978,
"title": "Archive",
"duration": 2063,
"public": true,
"is_loved_track": false,
"collaborative": true,
"rating": 5,
"link": "http://www.deezer.com/playlist/4341978",
"picture": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/playlist/4341978/image",
"creator": {
    "id": 2529
},
"type": "playlist",
"tracks": {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1152226,
            "readable": true,
            "title": "Darkroom",
            "link": "http://www.deezer.com/track/1152226",
            "duration": 271,
            "preview": "http://cdn-preview-6.deezer.com/stream/6452dbcd46c90a70cb1147666ffd91ae-0.mp3",
            "artist": {
                "id": 1334,
                "name": "Archive",
                "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1334"
            },
            "album": {
                "id": 123427,
                "title": "Londinium",
                "cover": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/album/123427/image"
            },
            "type": "track"
        },
        {
            "id": 708335,
            "readable": false,
            "title": "Again",
            "link": "http://www.deezer.com/track/708335",
            "duration": 980,
            "preview": "http://cdn-preview-d.deezer.com/stream/d8fe302b80c2be8a5fed4b8341f1286e-2.mp3",
            "artist": {
                "id": 1334,
                "name": "Archive",
                "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1334"
            },
            "album": {
                "id": 84795,
                "title": "You All Look The Same To Me (open disc)",
                "cover": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/album/84795/image"
            },
            "type": "track"
        },
        {
            "id": 778880,
            "readable": false,
            "title": "Fuck U",
            "link": "http://www.deezer.com/track/778880",
            "duration": 312,
            "preview": "http://cdn-preview-5.deezer.com/stream/505ca648dde07ce1288de4a8762f36e6-2.mp3",
            "artist": {
                "id": 1334,
                "name": "Archive",
                "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1334"
            },
            "album": {
                "id": 91316,
                "title": "Noise",
                "cover": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/album/91316/image"
            },
            "type": "track"
        },
        {
            "id": 1965620,
            "readable": true,
            "title": "Stairway To Heaven",
            "link": "http://www.deezer.com/track/1965620",
            "duration": 500,
            "preview": "http://cdn-preview-3.deezer.com/stream/3a1e4062efacdef98745cc2e05c84b66-1.mp3",
            "artist": {
                "id": 1548,
                "name": "Dweezil Zappa",
                "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/1548"
            },
            "album": {
                "id": 199616,
                "title": "Led Box - The Ultimate Led Zeppelin Tribute",
                "cover": "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/album/199616/image"
            },
            "type": "track"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Here is my Asynctask

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = ""; 

protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading your data...");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
            MyAsyncTask.this.cancel(true);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    String url_select = "http://api.deezer.com/2.0/playlist/4341978";

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try {
        // Set up HTTP post

        // HttpClient is more then less deprecated. Need to change to URLConnection
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        // Read content & Log
        inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e1.toString());
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
        Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
        Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
        e3.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e4) {
        Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
        e4.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Convert response to string using String Builder
    try {
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        inputStream.close();
        result = sBuilder.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("StringBuilding & BufferedReader", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
} // protected Void doInBackground(String... params)


protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

    //parse JSON data
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = jObject.getString("title");
            String tab1_text = jObject.getString("type");
            int active = jObject.getInt("tracks");


            System.out.println("name: "+name+"\n");
            System.out.println("tab1_text: "+tab1_text+"\n");
            System.out.println("active: "+active+"\n");


        } // End Loop

        this.progressDialog.dismiss();

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());

    } // catch (JSONException e)


} // protected void onPostExecute(Void v)
```

} //class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask

How can i solved this error please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(result);
```

You don't have a json array. Its a json object.

`{` represents a json object node.
`[` represents a json array node

```
"tracks": { // json object
"data": [   // json array
"title": "Darkroom",  // json string
 ...
```

Edit:

```
 JSSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result); 
 JSONObject jb1 = jsono.getJSONObject("tracks");
 JSONArray jar = jb1.getJSONArray("data");
 for(int i=0;i<jar.length();i++)
 {
    JSONObject jb2= (JSONObject) jar.get(i);
    String title = jb2.getString("title");
    Log.i("...",title);
 }
```

Comment: yes but now i am getting name: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

Comment: i am extracting the json data using this access token frEo3KgGsj51d0167968249FXsFiKqP51d0167968283K3pNGH i need to authenticate with this i guess. here is the link http://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer?url=playlist/4341978#

Comment: no i am not asking for the link. what information you need to get from json?

Comment: only the "tracks" and its contents

Comment: @Dimitri i will show you example. you need to parse the rest.

Comment: @ Raghunandan: ok thanks but Json parsing is not the problem. I need to set an access token to get the json response first

Comment: no i am getting name: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user","type":"OAuthException","code":200}} i need to authenticate with the token. do you know how to authenticate with this token ?

Comment: when you log the json do you see the log in logcat? The parsing part is fine i am sure about that

Comment: i believe the parsing is good too but i need to authenticate with the access token to confirm. however i dont know how to set the access token when sending my request

Comment: that is is different question post a new question may be someone can help you.